# How to make World Space UI always visible in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm creating simple VR game for google cardboard in Unity and I created UI Text which displays score and is child of the camera. My problem is that I can't make it always visible. I know that it works with Screen Space - Overlay but how to do it with World Space Canvas?

Comment: Create a second camera, set its Culling Mask to `UI` only, and assign it to the UI Canvas. Is there a reason why you dont want to use this approach?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko I'm not sure if it will work correctly with google cardboard camera(it's basically two cameras one for each eye). How should Ido this? Create another camera for each eye and set its Culling Mask tp UI?

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko If I manage to created second camera(s) with UI Culling mask how can i make it reender last?

Comment: just add canvas to child object of your main character. So it will move and rotate same with your character.

Comment: @BarışÇırıka I alreadyd did it but when i look down its behind terrain and I can't see it

Comment: @faken Your UI camera needs to clear the depth buffer before rendering. You can control this in the camera's inspector settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a shader I'm using to do it :

```
Shader "UI/Default_OverlayNoZTest"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _StencilComp("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
        _Stencil("Stencil ID", Float) = 0
        _StencilOp("Stencil Operation", Float) = 0
        _StencilWriteMask("Stencil Write Mask", Float) = 255
        _StencilReadMask("Stencil Read Mask", Float) = 255

        _ColorMask("Color Mask", Float) = 15
    }

        SubShader
    {
        Tags
    {
        "Queue" = "Overlay"
        "IgnoreProjector" = "True"
        "RenderType" = "Transparent"
        "PreviewType" = "Plane"
        "CanUseSpriteAtlas" = "True"
    }

        Stencil
    {
        Ref[_Stencil]
        Comp[_StencilComp]
        Pass[_StencilOp]
        ReadMask[_StencilReadMask]
        WriteMask[_StencilWriteMask]
    }

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        ZTest Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        ColorMask[_ColorMask]

        Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    struct appdata_t
    {
        float4 vertex   : POSITION;
        float4 color    : COLOR;
        float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    struct v2f
    {
        float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
        fixed4 color : COLOR;
        half2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
    };

    fixed4 _Color;
    fixed4 _TextureSampleAdd; //Added for font color support

    v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
    {
        v2f OUT;
        OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
        OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
        #ifdef UNITY_HALF_TEXEL_OFFSET
        OUT.vertex.xy += (_ScreenParams.zw - 1.0)*float2(-1,1);
        #endif
        OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
        return OUT;
    }

    sampler2D _MainTex;

    fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
    {
        half4 color = (tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) + _TextureSampleAdd) * IN.color;  //Added for font color support
        clip(color.a - 0.01);
        return color;
    }
        ENDCG
    }
    }
}
```

1. Create this shader in your project
2. Create a material with this shader
3. Apply the material to all your elements you want to appear in front of everything

Source http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/878667/world-space-canvas-on-top-of-everything.html

Comment: How can we make the UI elements don't kill zdepth on each other I mean they are showing top of everything but their own is based on their sort in canvas how to make it exactly like unity editor 3d icons ?